# Exception in createBlockOutputStream java.io.IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system, apache-tez

Any idea why I am getting this error? `10.0.1.193` is one of my slave VMs.

```
ubuntu@anmol-vm1-new:/home/hadoop/yarnpp$ hadoop fs -put tez-0.4.1-incubating/* /apps/tez-0.4.1-incubating 
15/11/30 02:53:28 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/11/30 02:54:40 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.io.IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as 10.0.1.193:50010
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:525)
15/11/30 02:54:40 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning BP-342182973-10.0.1.190-1448834909392:blk_1073741851_1028
15/11/30 02:54:40 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Excluding datanode 10.0.1.193:50010
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the firewall is blocking traffic to the data node. Open the following ports on  datanode machines (10.0.0.193 in your case).

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 50010 -m comment --comment "Port 50010  datanode" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 50020 -m comment --comment "Port 50020  datanode" -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling ports on firewall like in the answer given above.
If nothing works, just disable the firewall for time being.

`sudo ufw disable`